# PayPal SSL error / issue

Tags: ssl, paypal, sslv3

I keep getting this message while trying to communicate with the paypal api

here's my PayPal Class

```
<?php
class MyPayPal {

    function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode) {
            // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
            $API_UserName = urlencode($PayPalApiUsername);
            $API_Password = urlencode($PayPalApiPassword);
            $API_Signature = urlencode($PayPalApiSignature);

            $paypalmode = ($PayPalMode=='sandbox') ? '.sandbox' : '';

            $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t".$paypalmode.".paypal.com/nvp";
            $version = urlencode('109.0');

            // Set the curl parameters.
            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

            // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


            // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
            $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

            // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

            // Get response from the server.
            $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

            if(!$httpResponse) {
                exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
            }

            // Extract the response details.
            $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

            $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
            foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
                $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
                if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
                    $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
                }
            }

            if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
                exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
            }

        return $httpParsedResponseAr;
    }

}
?>
```

And I get this response on the remote server:

```
SetExpressCheckout failed: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure(35)
```

I've read some threads in there about it, but none seems to help at all.

I understand that PayPal is doing something with their apis, but the thing is, my code works just fine with localhost, but seems to fail while on the remote server (wich I also got SSL certificates just in case, and nothing has changed either)

Can someone please explain me, as if I was DUMB what's the procedure I should follow? Server side say it's not their fault... (I don't know how true that is tho...)

Edit: 2 weeks ago, same exact code, worked just fine in the server btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about the [POODLE Vunlerability](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vunerability//) and follow the info in that guide to fix it.

PayPal just officially flipped the switch on 1/19/16, so that's why your stuff worked before and doesn't now.

Comment: The guys from the server say it's not their problem/end. That other clients do not have issue with paypal, therefore, it has to be me. (yet, i bet all those clients are in production, meaning, until june paypal will keep accepting whatever protocols they are throwing at them)

Comment: Yes, exactly.  They're going to be in for a rude awakening come June.  I would recommend you find yourself a new host if they're unwilling to work with you.  This is a widely known issue.

Comment: I've jsut listed my local TLS version (using OpenSSL 1.0.1g meaning I do have support for TLS 1.2 locally, they are running version 0.9.8... wich limits me to TLS 1.0... well... That's fun... I just wanted to set my online shop running this week and I don't know what to do now... =.=

BTW, is it mandatory to have SSL certificates too? It worked 2 weeks ago and I had none, they charged me 120€ for a year of SSL support, but... before was not needed, will it be now?

Btw, thanks for keeping this up

Comment: You do not need an SSL certificate installed on the site.  You just need to make sure the software stack on the server (ie. OpenSSL, cURL, PHP) can handle fallback to TLS 1.2.

Comment: so, since they gave me 1 month trial, I'll be cancelling the SSL cert purchase then and demanding the money back. Later today I'll call them again about the openSSL... if not... time to get a now host and f**k them... yesterday the guy who talked to me over the phone was getting cocky over it and me being wrong and developing poor SW... ^^'

Comment: It's more expensive, but I always recommend a VPS.  Then the whole thing is yours so when stuff like this comes up there's no worry about breaking other people's sites, and then hosts will do it for you.  Unless you're reselling and hosting other people's sites on your own VPS, of course.  And then you'd probably understand why they don't want to update their's.  ;)